# How to do a weighted sum when using groupBy in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sum, grouping

I have made up an example because the context and details of my dataset might be too much/unnecessary to explain to deliver my question. While my example might be silly, just know that the example does illustrate what I am hoping to achieve (although at a much much larger scale) and is very important to the given problem. In this example, imagine we have different users (denoted by an alphabetical letter). Each user share multiple posts, and different users often times share the same post. We then come up with a importance score (either 0 or 1 indicating whether important) and reliability score (on a scale from 1-10). Although it is completely irrelevant how these metrics are computed for the sake of this question, imagine importance perhaps analyzes content and context/current events, and reliability takes into account prior performance of this source/user. It is not clear as to whether there is a relationship between importance and reliability

```
User       Share                      Importance            Reliability

 A         Carrots are                     0                     3
           good for eyesight

 B         Apple Cider Vinegar             1                     4
           is good for pain

 C         Garlic is good for breadth      0                     7

 A         Garlic is good for breadth      1                     6
 B         Carrots are good for eyesight   1                     9
```

The numbers might not make sense -- apologies Regardless, I want to do some sort of weighted sum for each text that takes into account the reliability and importance. To do so, I want to find each unique text (indicated by the share column) and sum the product of the importance and reliability scores for all the users who have shared that text. Therefore, I get something like:

```
A   6
B   13
C   0
```

I would love sample code and suggestions as to how to solve this question! Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can make a new column of the product of multiplication between `importance` and `reliability`. Then you can `groupby` by `user`.

Comment: You are saying you want - for some unique text that has been shared by users summation of product of the importance and reliability scores for each user. Your expected result table seems not reflecting the statement above. Instead it's showing summation of product for all posts and not unique post. IMO, there should have been one more column - `Share` in expected result table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First multiple columns by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html) and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

Advantage of `groupby` by column as `Series` is no temporary column is necessary.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['A','B','C','A','B'], 
                   'Importance':[0,1,0,1,1], 
                   'Reliability':[3,4,7,6,9]})
print (df)
   Importance  Reliability User
0           0            3    A
1           1            4    B
2           0            7    C
3           1            6    A
4           1            9    B

df1 = df.Importance.mul(df.Reliability).groupby(df['User']).sum().reset_index(name='col')
print (df1)
  User  col
0    A    6
1    B   13
2    C    0
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
df.groupby('User').apply(lambda g: (g.Importance*g.Reliability).sum())
```

Or you can precreate the product column and just sum that:

```
df['Score'] = df.Importance * df.Reliability
df.groupby('User').Score.sum()
```

(These both assume that a single user does not share the same article more than once.)

Answer (score 2):

This just in from

```
PROJECT
-------
 KILL
```

Project Overkill... just incase you didn't get it.
And please don't accept this answer!  This is just me having fun.  Yes, I believe this can be useful to many others.  No, I don't think this is necessary.  @jezrael's answer is what you want.

Using `numba` for disturbing optimization on a very simple problem

```
from numba import njit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

u = df.User.values
i = df.Importance.values
r = df.Reliability.values
f, q = pd.factorize(u)

@njit
def wghtd_sum(i, r, f):
    o = np.zeros(f.max() + 1, dtype=np.int64)
    for j in range(r.size):
        o[f[j]] += r[j] * i[j]
    return o

pd.DataFrame(dict(User=q, col=wghtd_sum(i, r, f)))
```

---

**Timing**
*tiny data*

```
%%timeit
u = df.User.values
i = df.Importance.values
r = df.Reliability.values
f, q = pd.factorize(u)
pd.DataFrame(dict(User=q, col=wghtd_sum(i, r, f)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 446 µs per loop

%timeit df.groupby('User').apply(lambda g: (g.Importance*g.Reliability).sum()).reset_index(name='col')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.51 ms per loop

%timeit df.Importance.mul(df.Reliability).groupby(df['User']).sum().reset_index(name='col')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 ms per loop
```

*large data*

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        User=np.random.choice(list(ascii_uppercase), 100000),
        Importance=np.random.randint(2, size=100000),
        Reliability=np.random.randint(10, size=100000)
    ))

%%timeit
u = df.User.values
i = df.Importance.values
r = df.Reliability.values
f, q = pd.factorize(u)
pd.DataFrame(dict(User=q, col=wghtd_sum(i, r, f)))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.45 ms per loop

%timeit df.groupby('User').apply(lambda g: (g.Importance*g.Reliability).sum()).reset_index(name='col')
100 loops, best of 3: 14.1 ms per loop

%timeit df.Importance.mul(df.Reliability).groupby(df['User']).sum().reset_index(name='col')
100 loops, best of 3: 4.45 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

As far as the wording of your question goes, I think you want summation of product of `Importance` and `Reliability` for each unique **post** and each unique **user**.

Here's sample dataframe similar to your's-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['A','B','C','A','B'],'Share':['Random Post 1','Random post 2','Random Post 3','Random Post 3','Random Post 1'], 'Importance':[0,1,0,1,1],'Reliability':[3,4,7,6,9]})
=>
       Importance  Reliability      Share       User
0           0            3      Random Post 1    A
1           1            4      Random post 2    B
2           0            7      Random Post 3    C
3           1            6      Random Post 3    A
4           1            9      Random post 1    B
```

First get a new column `Product`-

```
df['Product'] = df.Importance.mul(df.Reliability)
=>
       Importance  Reliability      Share       User  Product
0           0            3      Random Post 1    A       0
1           1            4      Random post 2    B       4
2           0            7      Random Post 3    C       0
3           1            6      Random Post 3    A       6
4           1            9      Random post 1    B       9
```

Now, just group by `Share` and `User` and sum over `Product` to get desired result-

```
df.groupby(['Share','User'])['Product'].sum().reset_index(name='Score')
=>
    Share      User
Random Post 1   A       0
                B       9
Random Post 3   A       6
                C       0
Random post 2   B       4
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: If this solves your problem then you can accept the answer :-)